# Convert a date in nvarchar to date format in a table on the SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here is what I have done:

```
select top 1000 convert(nvarchar(50), cast([date written] as datetime), 1) 
from practicetable
where convert(nvarchar(50), cast([date written] as datetime), 1) = '09/07/16'
```

Although this query works on a small scale anytime I try to select more than 1000 records the query fails and I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string

Why can't I select more than 1,000 records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always risky to save dates as a string.  Since you don't have Try_Convert() in 2008, I would recommend that you

```
select distinct [date written] from practicetable order by 1
```

to see which dates are not formatted correctly, and scrub as necessary

Comment: I see it many times , why we have data types if we don't use it , I don't know why most of users use varchar to store date

Comment: @Sami I know, it breaks my heart, however, I have inherited such databases... and far, far worse.  :)

Comment: Thanks.  I have found the corrupt data!

Comment: @tnbumbray Never had a doubt.  Data hygiene is a constant battle

Answer (score 0):

The query is failing because it is trying to convert a string to a date, but the string does not fit the date format.  In other words, the 'Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string'.  You should take a closer look at the underlying data to determine which record is causing the issue.